# Help diagnosing broken windscreen wiper on MK5 GOLF with loud noise

Tags: noise, vw, golf, windshield-wipers

Upon starting the engine and activating the wipers, they move approximately 20 degrees before halting abruptly. Simultaneously, what I believe to be the wiper motor emits a loud droning noise for about 5 seconds. After this, the wipers remain motionless in the new position. Turning off and restarting the engine  and then activating the wipers causes the wipers to instantly reset to their original position but then move 20 degrees and make the noise again.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

- I've verified that the fuses for the wiper system are intact.
- There are no obvious obstructions, and the wiper blades can be manually moved slightly, suggesting they're not jammed.

**Questions:**

- Does this issue point towards a defective wiper motor, or could it be related to the linkage or electrical system?
- Is the loud droning noise indicative of a particular fault within the wiper system?

Comment: To diagnose this problem, best to remove the wiper arms and cowl so you can see the motor's crank arm and linkage to determine what's binding. I've had my MK4 apart a couple times for cleaning and re-greasing, which is all it has needed so far. This post with photos may help: https://www.vwvortex.com/threads/diy-mkv-wiper-linkage-fix.4880869/

Comment: Thanks I'm just waiting for a wiper removal tool to arrive. One concern I have is that since they are locked in a 20 degree position do I need to somehow mark this position of the wiper relevant to the spindle?

Comment: No harm in marking if you wish, but for me the easiest way to recalibrate position is - with the arms off - let the mechanism return to home, then attach the arms at their normal resting position at the bottom of the windshield. Works every time.

Comment: Understood - thank you